# How to write name under molecule?

Tags: chemfig

How can I add a name under the molecule? I want to add "Cellulose":

[image]

I only have this so far:

[image]

```
$\chemfig{[:30]6((<HO)-(<:OH)-(<:O>:6(-(<HO)-(<:OH)-(<:O)-O-(<)--))-O-(<)--)}$
```

Comment: try `underset` https://math-linux.com/latex-26/faq/latex-faq/article/latex-overset-and-underset. For example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
$A \underset{f}{\rightarrow} B$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemname[5ex]{\chemfig{
    [:30]*6((<HO)-(<:OH)-(<:O>:*6(-(<HO)-(<:OH)-(<:O-[@{cl,0.5},1.2])-O-(<-[:60]OH)--))-O-(<-[:60]OH)-(-[@{op,0.5},1.2])-)
    }}{
    \huge Cellulose \vspace{1ex} \\
    \huge $(\chemfig{C_6H_{10}O_5})_n$
    }
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 19ex, depth = 14ex, indice=\!\mbox{$n$}]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: Why doesnt this work in discord tho?

Comment: Can you come to discord and help with texit bot maybe?

Comment: I copy and pasted this to discord, but it shows a bit differecnt, cant sent a phot here tho

Comment: Ok its just the \polymerdelim the Big Bracket that is a bit off

Comment: The Bracket is way to the right, what can i do?

Comment: Please come help

Comment: you can change the value of @{op,0.5} and @{cl,0.5} to 0.2 or 0.8

Comment: sry in discord there is just a bug that isnt fixed yet

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not in chemistry major, just give some tries. I like to embbed chemistry figures and formulae in TikZ `node` (highly customize).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}     % for chemistry figures and formulae
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
Here is an example.
\[\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}
   \underset{\delta x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}
f'(x)\]

And this is another \verb|chemfig| example.
\def\mych{\chemfig{
    [:30]*6((<HO)-(<:OH)-(<:O>:*6(-(<HO)-(<:OH)-(<:O-[@{cl,0.5},1.2])-O-(<-[:60]OH)--))-O-(<-[:60]OH)-(-[@{op,0.5},1.2])-)
    }}

\[\underset{\text{Cellulose}}{\mych}\]

I propose a TikZ way:
\newsavebox{\boxCh}
\savebox{\boxCh}{$\mych$}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (C) {\usebox{\boxCh}};
\path (C.south) node[below=5mm,scale=1.5,align=center,red]{Cellulose\\
$(\chemfig{C_6H_{10}O_5})_n$
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```